# Samba stopped working over LAN

Tags: networking, samba, iptables, firewall

I have been using SAMBA to share files on my HTPC and it worked fine until now. I haven't touched the HTPC in over a month and today the sharing suddenly stopped working by itself.

I traced the problem down to iptables. 
Currently I use this set of rules and up until now the samba worked flawlessly:

```
~$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 61 packets, 4786 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  102  6843 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere             /* This allows all traffic on localhost. */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  enp4s2 any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns /* Samba LAN */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  enp4s2 any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm /* Samba LAN */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp4s2 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn /* Samba LAN */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  enp4s2 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds /* Samba LAN */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 80 packets, 11372 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I have managed to get the samba working by changing  Chain INPUT (policy DROP) to  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT), but obviously this is just a temporary fix, since I don't want the htpc to just accept any suspicious incoming traffic.

Any idea why it stopped working all the sudden?

Thanks